On the type of a pointer to a class method using deducting this
The type of a pointer to a class method using deducting this matches the type of a pointer to a free function:
#include <iostream>

struct TA
{
   void Foo(this auto&& self)
   {
       std::cout << "Foo call\n";
   }
};

void test_TA()
{
    TA  a;
    void (*fun_ptr)(TA&) = &TA::Foo<TA&>;
    (*fun_ptr)(a);
}

int main()
{
    test_TA();
}

This is somewhat counter-intuitive. Why was this design adopted? Is there any difficulty for compilers in using the ordinary type of a pointer to a class method (void (TA::*mem_ptr)() &) in this case? It would be intuitive.

Have you read the deducing this paper?

From the paper, there is a FAQ about this:

6.3 Function Pointer Types
A valid question to ask is what should be the type of this-annotated functions that have a member function equivalent? There are only two options, each with a trade-off. Please assume the existence of these three functions:

struct Y {
    int f(int, int) const&;         // exists
    int g(this Y const&, int, int); // this paper
    int h(this Y, int, int);        // this paper, by value
};


g has a current equivalent (f), while h does not. &Y::h’s type must be a regular function pointer.
If we allow g’s type to be a pointer-to-member-function, we get non-uniformity between the types of h and g. We also get implementation issues because the types a template can result in are non-uniform (is this a template for a member function or a free function? Surprise, it’s both!).
We also get forward compatibility with any conceivable proposal for extension methods - those will also have to be free functions by necessity, for roughly the same reasons.
The paper originally proposed it the other way, but this was changed to the current wording through EWG input in Cologne, 2018.

